# Forcing a refresh of Alpinejs template on subcomponent update

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm encountering a problem on a Laravel/Livewire app getting an AlpineJS x-if template to re-render when a subcomponent updates. For the sake of simplicity, I'll explain the situation in broad terms, as I feel the issue lies in my approach and not in the execution. Here is the general setup:

LEFT MENU

- GROUP1
- ITEM1
- ITEM2
- ITEM3...

RIGHT MENU

- [template x-if=[$store.displayMode]]
- FIELD1 ($store.items[$store.activeIndex])
- FIELD2
- FIELD3...

The user can select a [GROUP] or [ITEM] in the left menu and the corresponding fields will be displayed in the right menu. Because the layout for GROUP and ITEM fields is different, I use a *displayMode* variable held in Alpine's $store object to determine what mode to display in the right menu. I also use an *activeIndex* variable to track which ITEM is being selected and access that information in a [ITEMS] array, which is also held in the $store.

This setup works when the *displayMode* variable changes (for example, group→item). However, the right menu does not refresh if I try clicking from item to item. For instance, if I first select ITEM1, then click on ITEM2, the right menu will still display the information related to ITEM1. I suspect the problem is that because the condition x-if is evaluating has not changed, Alpine is not refreshing the subcomponents of the template.

The only solution I have found so far is to briefly change the *displayMode* variable to null each time an ITEM is selected, set a 5ms timeout, then change it back to ITEM again. This hacky approach gets the job done, but it also causes a tiny flicker in the right menu and will likely create future problems. There is also the possibility this is being caused by Livewire, but I'm not utilizing any Livewire functionality at the moment, so it seems unlikely.

I realize this is all rather abstract, but I'm wondering if there a better way to handle this particular situation with Alpine. Any suggestions or corrections is highly appreciated!

Comment: The description is quite accurate, however without being able to see the code any answer cannot be effective enough. Please post the code.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem. After more digging, it appears my problem was setting an x-data object inside the template to the $store object, then using the x-data object. This was done mostly out of convenience because the reference was really long, but after swapping out the x-data reference with the $store reference, it works. Strange how the x-data approach will work except in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT- SOLUTION**

After more digging, I found my the cause of the problem. It turns out that I had set references to the $store inside the template as part of an x-data object. Something like this:

```
x-data="{group: $store.model.groups[$store.model.activeGroup]}"
```

I then proceeded to reference 'group' in the template, primarily out of convenience. But once I removed the x-data 'group' and simply referenced the groups with the `$store.model.groups[$store.model.activeGroup]` reference throughout the template, it worked as expected. The same holds true for items as well.

Strange how the other works in most cases, however. Does anybody with a deeper knowledge of **`alpinejs`** know why this is the case?